# Set server side text from javascript using form c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have asp lable

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl_qustionID" runat="server" Text="1" />
```

I set lable text to 6 using javascript

```
<button onclick="replayFrom('6')">set label number to 6</button>
```

My script function is :

```
<script>
            function replayFrom(qustionId) {
                document.getElementById("<%=lbl_qustionID.ClientID%>").innerText = qustionId;                
            }
</script>
```

When I check lable text from c# code behind label text is "1" allways !
I'm using .NET 2.0 Classic and WebForms
Thanks for suggesion

Comment: Javascript runs on the client(browser). How do you get the value back to your server?

Comment: As you know when post back raise, the value assigned from client side(java script) will be erase.

Answer (score 1):

```
<button onclick="replayFrom('6')">set label number to 6</button>
```

This button tag refresh your page. First its change label when you click on button but after that it will refresh the Page.

I will recommend you please use input tag when you deal with javascript and when do not need to communicate with server

```
  <input type="button" onclick="replayFrom('6')" value="button"/>
```

Comment: this button in asp Grid view 
`<button style="margin-right: 5%;" onclick="replayFrom2('<%# Eval("questionID") %>')"><span class="fa fa-reply" style="color: blue"></span></button>`
when 
`<input type="button" onclick="replayFrom2('<%# Eval("questionID") %> ')" value="button"/> `
its not work

Comment: sorry its too late to response i think you solve your problem?